# how reading nutch generated content data on the segment folder using java

Tags: nutch

I am trying to read the content data inside the segment folder. I think the content data file is written in a custom [format](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchFileFormats)

I experimented with nutch's [Content](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/nutch/nutch-1.3/org/apache/nutch/protocol/Content.java.html) class, but it does not recognize the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.apache.nutch.segment.SegmentReader
```

has a map reduce implementation that reads content data in the segment directory.

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.nutch.protocol.Content;
import org.apache.nutch.util.NutchConfiguration;

public class ContentReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Setup the parser
        Configuration conf = NutchConfiguration.create();
        Options opts = new Options();
        GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, opts, args);
        String[] remainingArgs = parser.getRemainingArgs();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        String segment = remainingArgs[0];
        Path file = new Path(segment, Content.DIR_NAME + "/part-00000/data");
        SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, file, conf);
        Text key = new Text();
        Content content = new Content();
        // Loop through sequence files
        while (reader.next(key, content)) {
            try {
                System.out.write(content.getContent(), 0,
                        content.getContent().length);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the above! any method that would help retrieve a given file type (docx, pdf, etc) only.

Comment: String contentType = content.getContentType();
         if(!contentType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")) {

Comment: awesome! thanks! also what are the arguments that argv represents and the order?

Comment: the initial options are hadoop specific(detailed here:http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html). you can leave them out if you want. I just have one argument without any prefixes which is the crawl directory path.

Comment: can you suggest how to compile and run the above?

Answer (score 0):

spark/scala code to read data from the segments content folder.

How I read from the content folder in my project.

I have created a case class page which holds data read from the content folder

```
 case class Page(var url: String, var title: String = null
,var contentType: String = null, var rawHtml: String = null,var language: String = null
    ,var metadata: Map[String,String])
```

**Code to read from content folder**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{Text, Writable}
import org.apache.nutch.crawl.{CrawlDatum, Inlinks}
import org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseText
import org.apache.nutch.protocol.Content
    val contentDF = spark.sparkContext.sequenceFile(path.contentLocation, classOf[Text], classOf[Writable])
                    .map { case (x, y) => (x.toString, extract(y.asInstanceOf[Content])) }

/** converts Content object to Page **/
def extract(content: Content): Page = {
        try {
            val parsed = Page(content.getUrl)
            var charset: String = getCharsetFromContentType(content.getContentType)
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(charset)) {
                charset = "UTF-8"
            }
            parsed.rawHtml = Try(new String(content.getContent, charset)).getOrElse(new String(content.getContent, "UTF-8"))
            parsed.contentType = Try(content.getMetadata.get("Content-Type")).getOrElse("text/html")
            //      parsed.isHomePage = Boolean.valueOf(content.getMetadata.get("isHomePage"))
            
        parsed.metadata = content.getMetadata.names().map(name => (name,content.getMetadata.get(name))).toMap
        
            Try {
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(content.getMetadata.get("Content-Language")))
                    parsed.language = content.getMetadata.get("Content-Language")
                else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(content.getMetadata.get("language")))
                    parsed.language = content.getMetadata.get("language")
                else parsed.language = content.getMetadata.get("lang")
            }
            parsed
        } catch {
            case e: Exception =>
                LOG.error("ERROR while extracting data from Content ", e)
                null
        }
    }
/**Get Html ContentType **/
def getCharsetFromContentType(contentType: String): String = {
        var result: String = "UTF-8"
        Try {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(contentType)) {
                val m = charsetPattern.matcher(contentType)
                result = if (m.find) m.group(1).trim.toUpperCase else "UTF-8"
            }
        }
        result
    }
```