# Search & retrieve online documents

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine

I need to develop in Java an application capable of finding the documents (HTML, .doc, .pdf, etc.) available on the Web by considering only some particular filtering conditions (e.g., text included, domains, etc.) and then to download them all.

Which is the best way to do that? Should I use such a library (e.g. Guava?) or tool that already provides these features?

I know that there are a lot of libraries (Apache Solr, Apache Nutch, etc.), but I'm not really sure that they can accomplish all my tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Nutch should help you with this of what I understand.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506890/how-reading-nutch-generated-content-data-on-the-segment-folder-using-java/15764001?noredirect=1#comment22562363_15764001) and [allenday's post](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci572/2013Spring/homework/nutch/allenday20080829.html) should help you with the java code. Some reading about nutch will definitely be helpful.